# Is there a function to generate possible permutations given list of choices for each digit or index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation

I'm trying to generate the possible sequences given a list of choices for each index of the final list.

Example:
In the below dictionary I have 5 words and different values possible for each of the word.
I would like to generate all possible permutations or sequences.

`{'John': ['NNP'], 'went': ['VBD'], 'to': ['TO'], 'work': ['VBP', 'NN', 'VB'], '.': ['.']}`

In this example there would be 1 * 1 * 1 * 3 * 1 = 3 sequences.

Comment: Look at the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `itertools.product` function:

```
from itertools import product

arrs = [[1,2],[1],[1,2,3],[4]]

for combo in product(*arrs):
  print(combo)
```

Output:

```
(1, 1, 1, 4)
(1, 1, 2, 4)
(1, 1, 3, 4)
(2, 1, 1, 4)
(2, 1, 2, 4)
(2, 1, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, this is exactly what I was looking for!